# php call class method asynchronously

Tags: php, exec, background-process, popen

I need to call a PHP method in a loop asynchronously.

This is what I tried :

```
foreach ($batch_ids as $batch_id) {
          $this->launchBackgroundProcess( $this->sendBatchMail($batch_id) );
        }

public function launchBackgroundProcess($call) {

  // pclose( popen( $call.'/dev/null &', 'r'));     
  Proc_close( Proc_open( $call.' > /dev/null & ', 'r'));
  return true;
}
```

Now the error is that my function sendBatchMail is being called directly and launchBackgroundProcess is never called (used echo/print/log to check).

So if in a batch id there are 10k mails, endBatchcMail for next batch Id never starts.

> I wish to call sendBatchMail simultaneously and asynchronously in the background for all batch ids retreived.

I am not really well versed at pthreads... and seems to be my last stop.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really the way to go. Each PHP process is launched and torn down for every individual request. You shouldn't be attempting to directly launch anything directly from a PHP script answering an HTTP request. Its only job should be to return the HTTP response ASAP and then hang up. Any larger amounts of work should be queued up to be handled by a more persistent backend worker sometime later.

Which directly brings me to *message queues and workers*. Look at [Gearman](http://gearman.org) for a pretty simple such system, though there are any number of other possibilities, including ØMQ, Redis and others. You simply stuff a number of messages in this queue, which will then be handled by one or more PHP scripts running as cron job or persistent worker daemons in the background, entirely decoupled from the front-end HTTP handlers.

Comment: Thanks a lot deceze. My this php method to run mails is itself executed through a cron. But I want this to eventually asynchronize the individual batch_id calls too. Will go throught the link for better understanding of your suggestion.

Comment: Essentially you want to have *many processes running in parallel*. "Asynchronicity" is only tangential. Since PHP is not really an asynchronous language, the best way to get there is to control the number of parallel processes with the number of workers running, and control where those workers are getting their jobs from via a message queue.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is have a php script with the send code, and do:

```
shell_exec("theBackgroundScript.php >/dev/null &");
```

But it means you will have a lot of processes at the same time. Also, if one of them fails for some reason it is complicated to find and run it again.

Instead, consider creating a table in your database to hold all mail jobs. It could be like:

```
CREATE TABLE email_jobs (
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
executed TINYINT DEFAULT 0,
destination VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
subject VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
content TEXT NOT NULL,
created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL);
```

Then, you just need to add the details of each job when you need one:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO email_jobs (destination, subject, content, created_at) VALUES ('someperson@example.com', 'some subject', 'some email content', NOW())");
```

Then, you need a PHP script which will query the database for jobs not yet executed:

```
$row = $db->query("SELECT * FORM email_jobs WHERE executed = 0 LIMIT 1");
// ... send email described in $row
```

The script gets the first not executed job (or first N not executed jobs), and sends it.
Then you just need to put the script in [cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) and let it send all emails.

If one fails, it is very easy to send it again, just set the executed to zero, and it will be delivered.

Comment: Your shell_exec solution works flawlessly for me.  Many thanks!